# Changing Laravel Blade Delimiter

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I know that you can change the default blade delimiter using

```
Blade::setEscapedContentTags('[[', ']]');
Blade::setContentTags('[[[', ']]]');
```

However I don't know where should I put it so that it only affect single blade template as opposed to putting it at `app/start/global.php` which affect whole application.

Comment: Just in case, you mismatched your calls with the number of brackets. Content = 2 brackets/symbols, escapedcontent = 3. It'll probably have no side effect, but I'd try to stay close to the standard tags.

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/issues/1776#issuecomment-14808606

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you only want to use different tags for a single view, you can set the tags in the closure or controller action that will generate the view.

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    Blade::setEscapedContentTags('[[', ']]');
    Blade::setContentTags('[[[', ']]]');

    return View::make('home');
});
```

This could be an issue if you want to use the normal tags `{{` and `}}` in an application layout but your custom ones in a nested view - I'm not sure what the best approach there would be.

Comment: My controller view reference a master layout and I can confirm that the master layout are not affected.

Answer (score 3):

The solution with `Blade::setEscapedContentTags` / `Blade::setContentTags` doesn't work in the latest versions of Laravel (checked at 5.6).

The recommended approach is (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#blade-and-javascript-frameworks):

> #### Blade & JavaScript Frameworks
>
> Since many JavaScript frameworks also use "curly" braces to indicate a
>   given expression should be displayed in the browser, you may use the `@`
>   symbol to inform the Blade rendering engine an expression should
>   remain untouched. For example:
>
> `Hello, @{{ name }}.`
>
> In this example, the `@`symbol will be removed by
>   Blade; however, `{{ name }}` expression will remain untouched by the
>   Blade engine, allowing it to instead be rendered by your JavaScript
>   framework.
>
> #### The @verbatim Directive
>
> If you are displaying JavaScript variables in
>   a large portion of your template, you may wrap the HTML in the
>   `@verbatim` directive so that you do not have to prefix each Blade echo
>   statement with an `@` symbol:
>
> ```
> @verbatim
>     <div class="container">
>         Hello, {{ name }}.
>     </div> 
> @endverbatim
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use **@verbatim** directive.wrap your whole code in it and blade will just ignore all the curly braces.