# Laravel blade page not processing tags

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

I have a site that I'm deep into developing.  To keep the question simple, if I go into my welcome.blade.php (the standard Laravel welcome page), it is completely untouched.  I go right under the Laravel 5 written there and type:

```
{!! "<b>Foo!</b>" !!}
```

When I refresh the page in the browser, it literally says "{!! "**Foo!**" !!}" and not just **Foo!**.

To troubleshoot, I created a new project and put the same exact code in my welcome.blade.php and it worked.  So, what could be wrong with my site that I'm currently developing?  Both are on Laravel 5.1.20.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
{{ '<b>Foo!</b> }}
```

With `!!` I believe it will output the exact text inside it.

http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/36/displaying-a-variable-in-a-blade-template

**UPDATE**

After rechecking your question. I think this may help you [Changing Laravel Blade Delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363150/changing-laravel-blade-delimiter) since it's working with the exact laravel version.

Maybe you changed your existing blade delimeter in a specific controller or globally.

Answer (score 0):

you need curly braces only when processing php variables not raw html codes.
just use

```
<b>Foo!</b>
```

and it should work

Comment: That was just a simple example to show how blade isn't processing the code inside the braces.

Answer (score 0):

I found that under app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php on my old site, I had this section of code:

```
\Blade::setRawTags('{{', '}}');
\Blade::setContentTags('{{{', '}}}');
\Blade::setEscapedContentTags('{{{', '}}}');
```

I have no idea why that was in there (Perhaps left over from Laravel 4?).

At any rate, a fresh install of Laravel does not have that.

Comment: That is the standard way of emulating the Blade template tags from Laravel 4.